# how do I parent to a soft body?

Tags: animation, soft-body

I have a cube that's a soft body falling down some stairs.  I want to put a little sphere inside the cube and have it stay at the center of the cube while the cube falls.  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You could parent the child object to 3 vertices of the soft body object: Select the child, shift select the soft body object, go into *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*, and the child will follow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks again.